# How to access ViewModel property(value) in another ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, mvvm

I have a one ViewModel like this:

```
public class TaskTrayViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase where T : IBlotterRow, new()
{ }
```

this ViewModel contains one property :

```
private Product sp;
public Product selectedProduct
{
   get { return sp; }
   set
   {
    sp = value; 
   }
```

}

I want to access this property(value) in BlotterCriteriaViewModel (other viewModel). All the viewmodels implements InotiFyPropertyChange. I have read some related questions but didnt get anything. I am not using frameworks(prism,galasoft)?

How to pass the property(value) here? Kindly suggest>

Comment: check this out [Communication between two ViewModels][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808901/communication-between-viewmodels

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there are at least two ways.

1. Direct way: the instance of `BlotterCriteriaViewModel` gets a reference to the instance of `TaskTrayViewModel` (either at the construction time, or maybe at the point where the value is needed). Having the `TaskTrayViewModel` reference, public properties can be easily accessed.
2. Indirect way: the instance of `BlotterCriteriaViewModel` gets the `INotifyPropertyChange` reference from `TaskTrayViewModel` and subscribes to `PropertyChanged` event. You won't get the *initial* value of the property, but as soon as the property changes, you get the event and can see the new value in the event args.

Is there a problem with any of these?

Comment: In Direct Way..How to pass the reference to the instance of TaskTrayViewModel as TaskTrayViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase where T : IBlotterRow, new() to the instance of BlotterCriteriaViewModel. Tried with error - must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method. Kindly suggest with implementation?

Comment: @Tarun: could you please post the failing code? What are you using as `T`? Don't you already have an actual instance?

Comment: In BlotterCriteriaViewModel..I am doing like                  public TaskTrayViewModel<T> TaskViewModel { get; set; } where T = where T : IBlotterRow, new(). I am not able to create "TaskViewModel" as error is coming "must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method."

Comment: Hm. Is `BlotterCriteriaViewModel` a generic? What is `T` in that context?

Comment: BlotterCriteriaViewModel is not a generic but TaskTrayViewModel<T> is. where T : IBlotterRow, new()

Comment: @Tarun: When you declare a property, what should be the `T`? You cannot declare a property for an unknown `T`.

Comment: TaskTrayViewModel<T> where T is IBlotterRow, new()

Comment: Please describe the second way practically